# How do I check "if less than" for a version of jQuery-UI with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Example:

If jQuery-UI is v1.8.4 and I run this script:

```
var jqVersion = $.ui.version;
if (jqVersion < 1.9.0) {
    console.log("You currently have v" + jqVersion + ". Upgrade it");
}
```

So obviously this doesn't work.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mA9b6/

I just need to trigger the console warning if it's less than version 1.9

Comment: why do you want it? i mean a developer has to develop according to the requirements.

Comment: `(+($.ui.version.replace(/\.|\,/g,'').slice(0,2))) > 18`

Comment: @Jai Because it's for an end user and I'm saving myself support requests because people don't like reading documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Nano - I'm taking a look at that now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put quotes around the version you are testing for. The following resolves corretly:

```
var jqVersion = $.ui.version;

if (jqVersion < '1.9.0') {
    console.log("You currently have v" + jqVersion + ". Upgrade it");
}
```

Comment: Try it in your console: '1.10.1' < '1.9.0' returns true